# What's the general word for '样‘ in '这样，那样’，‘小样’, ‘怎样', ‘好样的’?

Tags: mandarin, word

It is hard for me to find out one general or exactly English word for '样' in different contexts, it is so common in Chinese.

Comment: They’re all short for 样子

Answer (score 1):

样 means 模样 or 样子 (manner/way; appearance/ look)

这样 = this way/ like this

那样 = that way/ like that

怎样 = what way/ like what/ how

小样的 = small looking one (mock people for being small minded or undignified)

好样的 = good looking one (use in positive way to praise someone looking good by doing something or use in ironic way to mock someone looking bad by doing something)

Comment: 小样 may also mean _(product) sample_ in some context